Dropzone JS showing up but with the normal file upload overtop of it
Dropzone JS is showing up like so:
Picture of problem with dropzonejs
I have called the CSS file in the head of my site:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />

And the JS file in footer with all the other JS (of course after the jquery).
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

Form Code:
<form action="#" id="upload" class="dropzone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required>
                                    </form>

I tried to move the javascript file to the header so it would be ran before the rest of the page loaded, but that did no change. I added basic config options like setting "clickable" to false and indeed it wouldn't let me click the area anymore to try and upload. But I cannot seem to get rid of the regular ol file upload thing.
Also, i uploaded something by dropping. It does try to do it. Only problem is the old file thing is still showing up for unknown reasoning.

you dont have to include another  by adding the class "dropzone" to the form dropzone already embeded its own file input
